# Asus G551JM Game Laptop Bluetooth and Microphone not working

Tags: usb, sound, bluetooth, microphone

lspci output:

```
xyphos@xyphos-G551JM:~$ lspci -k
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor DRAM Controller (rev 06)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 185d
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor PCI Express x16 Controller (rev 06)
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 185d
        Kernel driver in use: i915
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th Gen Core Processor HD Audio Controller (rev 06)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 2010
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB xHCI (rev 05)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 185d
        Kernel driver in use: xhci_hcd
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family MEI Controller #1 (rev 04)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 185d
        Kernel driver in use: mei_me
00:1a.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #2 (rev 05)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 185d
        Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset High Definition Audio Controller (rev 05)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 185d
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #1 (rev d5)
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #2 (rev d5)
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.2 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #3 (rev d5)
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family PCI Express Root Port #4 (rev d5)
        Kernel driver in use: pcieport
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family USB EHCI #1 (rev 05)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 185d
        Kernel driver in use: ehci-pci
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM86 Express LPC Controller (rev 05)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 185d
        Kernel driver in use: lpc_ich
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family 6-port SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 05)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 185d
        Kernel driver in use: ahci
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series/C220 Series Chipset Family SMBus Controller (rev 05)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 185d
01:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 860M] (rev a2)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 185d
        Kernel driver in use: nvidia
04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 6b)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Dual Band Wireless-N 7260
        Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
05:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device 5287 (rev 01)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 202f
        Kernel driver in use: rtsx_pci
05:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Device 200f
        Kernel driver in use: r8169
```

lsusb output:

```
xyphos@xyphos-G551JM:~$ lsusb
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 002: ID 8087:8008 Intel Corp. 
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 13d3:5188 IMC Networks 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 046d:c016 Logitech, Inc. Optical Wheel Mouse
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
xyphos@xyphos-G551JM:~$
```